# Displaying contents of a vector container in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector

The following is a C++ program using STL vector container. Just wanted to know why the  display() function is not printing the vector contents to the screen. If displaying the size() line is commented out, display() function works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void display(vector<int> &v)
{
    for(int i; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "Size of Vector=" << v.size() << endl;

    //Putting values into the vector
    int x;
    cout << "Enter five integer values" << endl;
    for(int i; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    //Size after adding values
    cout << "Size of Vector=" << v.size() << endl;

    //Display the contents of vector
    display(v);

    v.push_back(6);

    //Size after adding values
    cout << "Size of Vector=" << v.size() << endl;

    //Display the contents of vector
    display(v);

}
```

Output:

```
Size of Vector=0

Enter five integer values

1

2

3

4

5

Size of Vector=5


Size of Vector=6
```

Comment: initialize your variables! `int i = 0`

Comment: When you iterated through your vector to display, you clearly wanted to stop at the end. But where did you want to  *start*? :)   (P.S. enabling all warnings in your compiler might have caught this mistake for you)

Comment: You should really initialize your iterator variables ala `int i=0;` It is very dangerous to just assume that C++ has done you a favor and initialized them to `0`.

Comment: Did you debug the code using any debugger ? Looks like SO is slowly becoming a place where we want others to debug our code.

Comment: Oof, some poor edit reviewing there guys...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an idiomatic way for printing a vector out.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//note the const
void display_vector(const vector<int> &v)
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

This way is safe and doesn't require you to keep track of the vectors size or anything like that. It is also easily recognisable to other C++ developers.

This method works on other container types too that do not allow random access.

```
std::list<int> l;
//use l

std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

This works both ways with input too consider the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter int end with q" << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> v; //a deque is probably better TBH
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter<int>(v));

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

This version doesn't require any hard coding of size or manual management of the actual elements.

Comment: Use "\n" as the second parameter for `ostream_iterator` to add a newline to your output.

Comment: This is the idiomatic answer prior to 2011. Since 2011 we have `for (auto&& x : container) std::cout << x << " ";`

Answer (score 8):

You are not initializing your variables. `for(int i = 0;` not `for(int i;`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the easiest way to go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    int x;
    cout << "Enter five integer values" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); i++)
        cout<< v.at(i) <<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use compiler versions g++ 11 or more than then you simply use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector<int> v;
   int x;
   cout << "Enter five integer values" << endl;
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
   }

   for (auto i: v)
      cout<< i <<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found printing using for_each() very easy to understand and intuitive

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

main(){
vector<int> foo_bar{1,2,3,4,5};
auto print_array = [](const auto& o) {cout << o << " "; };
for_each(foo_bar.begin(), foo_bar.end(), print_array);
}
```